# RabbitMQ Commit not happening for messages sent in Spring transaction

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have seen a message loss issue occurring in production for flows running in Spring transaction annotated with @Transactional

In this use case record is persisted in database and message is sent to RabbitMQ and this entire operation is managed by Spring transaction.

After debugging in the development environment we found the following stack trace

```
RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll() line: 147 
ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceSynchronization.afterCompletion(int) line: 333 
TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(List<TransactionSynchronization>, int) line: 171 
JpaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).invokeAfterCompletion(List<TransactionSynchronization>, int) line: 990 
JpaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).triggerAfterCompletion(DefaultTransactionStatus, int) line: 965 
JpaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 786 
JpaTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).commit(TransactionStatus) line: 712 
TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) line: 631 
TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class<?>, InvocationCallback) line: 385
```

In AbstractPlatformTransactionManager class while docommit method is invoked in processcommit method, record is persisted into database

```
private void processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        try {
            boolean beforeCompletionInvoked = false;

            try {
                boolean unexpectedRollback = false;
                prepareForCommit(status);
                triggerBeforeCommit(status);
                triggerBeforeCompletion(status);
                beforeCompletionInvoked = true;

                if (status.hasSavepoint()) {
                    if (status.isDebug()) {
                        logger.debug("Releasing transaction savepoint");
                    }
                    unexpectedRollback = status.isGlobalRollbackOnly();
                    status.releaseHeldSavepoint();
                }
                else if (status.isNewTransaction()) {
                    if (status.isDebug()) {
                        logger.debug("Initiating transaction commit");
                    }
                    unexpectedRollback = status.isGlobalRollbackOnly();
                    **doCommit(status);**
                }
                else if (isFailEarlyOnGlobalRollbackOnly()) {
                    unexpectedRollback = status.isGlobalRollbackOnly();
                }

                // Throw UnexpectedRollbackException if we have a global rollback-only
                // marker but still didn't get a corresponding exception from commit.
                if (unexpectedRollback) {
                    throw new UnexpectedRollbackException(
                            "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only");
                }
            }
            catch (UnexpectedRollbackException ex) {
                // can only be caused by doCommit
                triggerAfterCompletion(status, TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_ROLLED_BACK);
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (TransactionException ex) {
                // can only be caused by doCommit
                if (isRollbackOnCommitFailure()) {
                    doRollbackOnCommitException(status, ex);
                }
                else {
                    triggerAfterCompletion(status, TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_UNKNOWN);
                }
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (RuntimeException | Error ex) {
                if (!beforeCompletionInvoked) {
                    triggerBeforeCompletion(status);
                }
                doRollbackOnCommitException(status, ex);
                throw ex;
            }

            // Trigger afterCommit callbacks, with an exception thrown there
            // propagated to callers but the transaction still considered as committed.
            try {
                triggerAfterCommit(status);
            }
            finally {
                **triggerAfterCompletion(status, TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_COMMITTED);**
            }
        }
        finally {
            cleanupAfterCompletion(status);         
        }
    }
```

Post this when triggerAfterCompletion is invoked which further invokes invokeAfterCompletion passing the list of synchronizations obtained by following

```
List<TransactionSynchronization> synchronizations = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations();
```

Finally the TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion is invoked which further invokes the RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll() where the message is committed by Spring AMQP

In production use case this commit is not happening and messages are not seen getting published to RabbitMQ queue.

We have verified this behavior by hitting RabbitMQ queue REST API and seen the "publish" and "deliver" fields count not getting increased, which confirms the fact that message loss is happening because messages are not getting committed by Spring AMQP and following is not getting invoked

```
RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll()
```

We suspect the TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations() might not be returning the synchronization needed at RabbitMQ level.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (as little code as possible) that exhibits this behavior so we can investigate.

Comment: Hi , we are having a hard time reproducing the issue in development environment, however the issue is frequent in production. The sooner we reproduce it here in development environment , will update here.

Comment: hi @GaryRussell I have posted a follow up in the answer section. Looking for your input.

Comment: We have two kind of flows for sending messages to RabbitMQ

 1. In Spring transaction  
 2. Without Spring transaction.

The current mentioned issue is specific to flows running in Spring transaction and as of now we have not been able to reproduce the issue in our development environment even after the executing multiple runs of multiple scenarios via our messaging framework component which uses Spring AMQP along with RabbitMQ.

Comment: We are planning to Rollout Diagonistic logging in production:-  Diagnostic logging in
   spring transaction flow, in our publisher code to find the state of
   ***TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations() and
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap()***. This will confirm
   our doubt that somehow in transaction flows while sending message
   resource for our connectionfactory  is present but Rabbit
   Synchronization is missing and due to this message is not committed

Comment: During our analysis of ***ConnectionFactoryUtils.bindResourceToTransaction()*** on we noticed that it only checks for resource in first if condition but does not check for synchronization. So, in case if a thread in Spring Transaction TransactionSynchronizationManager already holds the resource for connection Factory, then it will return the current resource and thus it will miss to register the synchronization.

Comment: We have already tested for non-spring transaction flows, that unbinding of the connectionFactory resource before calling RabbitTemplate convertAndSend will clean any leftover connection factory resource and will bind new resource and register synchronization and thus message will be committed by Spring AMQP

Do you see any concern in above?